# How to aggregate values for a row staring from that particular row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have a table like below :

| ID | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 |
| 2 | 300 |
| 3 | 100 |
| 4 | 50 |
| 5 | 1000 |
| 6 | 20 |

I want a row level sum for each row. Like for ID 1,it should be the sum of VALUEs from ID 1 to 6 , for ID 2 it should be 2 to 6 and like this .

My desired output should look like this :

| ID | VALUE | AGG_VAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 | 1670 |
| 2 | 300 | 1470 |
| 3 | 100 | 1170 |
| 4 | 50 | 1070 |
| 5 | 1000 | 1020 |
| 6 | 20 | 20 |

Comment: Try the `SUM` analytic function

Comment: Please don't use keyboard markup for tables; [so] supported markdown tables.

Comment: *"I am using SQL Server 2018."* You can't be; there is no such thing. There were releases in 2017 and 2019, but there was not in 2018.

Comment: yes , 2019. sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use OVER function:

```
SELECT ID, 
       VALUE, 
       SUM(VALUE) OVER (ORDER BY ID DESC) AS AGG_VAL
FROM TableName
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: Otherwise known as an "analytic" function.